# IIS 7.0 error HTTP Error 500.19 -Internal Server Error (Error Code 0x80070003)

Tags: .net, iis-7

I have got IIS7 running on my Windows 2008 Server
It works perfectly working for the sites and the folder that I hosted before.
Now I am trying to host a folder which contains two subfolder(the subfolders contain some
images).

I have correctly set the IIS_IUSRS permissions on the site folder. When I try to browse
the folder I got the following error,

HTTP Error 500.19 -Internal Server Error
The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page
is invalid

Module: CustomErrorModule
Notification: SendResponse
Handler: Not yet determined
ErrorCode: 0x80070003
ConfigError: Cannot read configurationFile
ConfigFile: \?
            \H:\EMRImages\web.config
RequestedURL: https://localhost:443/EMRMachineIamge
PhysicalPath:H:\EMRImages
LogonMethod: Not yet determind
Logonuser:Not yet determind

** the same thing is working fine in previously host folder in the same IIS 7.0.Please help me,thanks in advance

Answer (score 6):

I have had a very similar error. The line:

```
\\?\H:\EMRImages\web.config
```

typically implies you've configured IIS to try and serve a website over mapped network drive (the `\\?\` is the giveaway), this happened to me because my profile maps the drive on `W:`, although it was native to the machine on `E:`. As soon as I corrected the drive error, everything was working correctly.

0x80070003 does seem to be specifically related to this network drive issue, although I believe this Microsoft KB Article goes into some detail on it: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/207671

Comment: I confess I was going crazy with this one! :) The network mapped drive was the culprit. Thanks for the insight.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same error and found that I had another application configured on the sub folder in IIS.
Perhaps try removing the applications and recreating them?

Answer (score 1):

In my case I unwittingly renamed the folder with the website.

Comment: Same here. I changed the folder containing the project and IIS still looks for it in old dir.

Comment: Solution in this case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33276878/iis-express-500-19-cannot-read-configuration-file-because-its-looking-at-th